# Android : Disable the Sensors when soft keyboard is visible

Tags: java, android, sensors

I want disable the Sensors system widely in Android devices when a soft keyboard is visible. So that no one can infer which key you press with the sensor information. However, to ensure no other third party apps can disable the sensors maliciously, I want to do this in the kernel level. My idea is add a static variable in the SensorManager, and check if it is true when handling sensor events. In InputMethodManager/InputMethodService, I will call a static function to set the variable according to the status of keyboard.

FYI, the version of Android I works on is 2.3.7.

**UPDATE** :

The following is the code I add to ANDROID_SOURCE/framework/core/java/hardware/SensorManager.java

```
static public class MyBoolean {
  public boolean value;
}
public volatile static MyBoolean inputActive;
private static final Object inputLock = new Object();
static {
  synchronized(inputLock) {
    inputActive = new MyBoolean();
    Log.v(TAG, "init input active : " + inputActive.hashCode());
    inputActive.value = false;
}

public static void setInputActive(boolean v) {
  synchronized(inputLock) {
    Log.v(TAG, "set input active : " + v);
    inputActive.value = v;
    Log.v(TAG, "after set input active : " + inputActive.value + " " +  SensorManager.inputActive.value + " " + inputActive.hashCode() + " " + SensorManager.inputActive.hashCode());
  }
}
```

In ANDROID_SOURCE/framework/core/java/inputmethodservice/InputMethodService.java, I call SensorManager.setInputActive(true) in the showSoftInputMethod function.

I'm pretty sure that the function is called because there is an output statement in the function. But when I check the value in SensorManager, it never changes. Why it won't change?

Comment: StackOverflow is for programming questions, and this is not a question.

Comment: Sorry for not making it clear.